# Problem running project after Identity scaffolding in ASP.NET Core MVC project on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I've tried adding

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime" Version="2.2.0" />
```

However 2.2.0 is the latest version available at this time, which doesn't match the error. The error is still the same after rebuilding the app.

project.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Full error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, Version=3.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, Version=3.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken
>   caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule,
>   MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean
>   mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType&
>   attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters,
>   Boolean& isVarArg)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1&
>   attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32
>   decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean
>   mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[T](Assembly
>   element)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(Assembly
>   assembly)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateDefaultParts(String
>   entryAssemblyName)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersCore(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViewsCore(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViews(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddRelatedParts(IdentityBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddDefaultUI(IdentityBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.AddDefaultIdentity[TUser](IServiceCollection
>   services, Action`1 configureOptions)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.AddDefaultIdentity[TUser](IServiceCollection
>   services)    at pieshop.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services) in /home/juan/code/web-projects/pieshop/src/Startup.cs:line
>   36    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
>   Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean
>   wrapExceptions)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object
>   instance, IServiceCollection services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection
>   serviceCollection)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object
>   instance, IServiceCollection services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type
>   startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext
>   context, IServiceCollection services)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
>   pieshop.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   /home/juan/code/web-projects/pieshop/src/Program.cs:line 10

Line 36 of Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Solved!
I uninstalled the dotnet packages separately in the following order:
dotnet-sdk-bin (AUR)
dotnet-runtime-bin (AUR)
dotnet-host-bin (AUR)

Then I built these same packages in the reverse order.
Now they are all at 3.1.1.sdk101-2 as of today and my project is running again.

Comment: Best would be to reinstall Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime package

Comment: With me the issue was that the SDK update was not installed, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1 after I did that the DLL hell solved itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had noticed the same thing, please look at the ms updates for the framework, there was an update a few days ago that the newer nuget packages expect to have been installed.

The issue you are having is that the nuget packages are not matching your SDk, at least that's what I had. After doing a windows update and installing the new Core Runtime, Version=3.1.1.0 all was okey

Comment: This helped me. What I did though is right-click on project from solution explorer -> manage nuget packages -> go to updates tab and update the available updates.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by reinstalling:
.Net Core SDK 3.1.101
and
ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.1

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the latest 3.1.1 release of ASP.NET Core Identity Packages. It works fine when I revert to the previous stable 3.1.0 version. See below snapshot:

To me, installing the latest SDK and Core Runtime did not resolve the issue.

[Affected Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVErd.png)